# jQuery Ajax Success is not called in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery.

I have below JQuery Code which working fine in Firefox, however it is not working in Internet Explorer.

1) Test Alert is not coming in after the Jquery Ajax call. Below is the code.

```
    $('#skywardsLogoutLink').click(function()
    {   
        var reloadUrl = window.location.href;           
         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/english/index_2011.aspx",
                data: { logout: "true" },
                success: function (data)
                {
                    alert(reloadUrl);                
                    window.location.href = reloadUrl;
                }
            });

    });
```

Above code is working fine in Firefox, however not working for Internet Explorer 6.0, I have used test **alert** to test it but not working. Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be worth trying what this guy did: http://patrickgibson.com/news/andsuch/000202.php

Comment: My Dear the problem is not with window.location.href, the actual problem is with ajax success call, However thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Does alert(reloadUrl); work outside of the success function, in IE6?

Comment: yes as well as the ajax beforesend is also called, I have checked with the alert in it and its coming up

Comment: If the success callback isn't being executed, it could be throwing an error, have you tried adding an error handler to the request? error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {} ? You may be able to get some useful information from that?

Answer (score 0):

First guess: javascript is disabled on localhost^^

2nd: Are you sure that you call the page containing your script using the port, otherwise it's related to same-origin-policy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Molle, regarding the javascript disable, I am sure it is enable as the POST is happening as I have checked it by putting break point in my code and regarding same origin policy, it is in the same domain.

Comment: same origin means same port too.